# Repairing table in mysql

Tags: mysql

i tried to repair a table in mysql .... 
but it returned an error like ..

```
The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair
```

plz try to help..

Comment: What lead you to attempt to repair the table?

Comment: Find out what storage engine you're using and then check MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check which storage engine the table is using:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tablename';
```

REPAIR TABLE only works for the MyISAM, ARCHIVE and (lately) CSV storage engines, according to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html). For other storage engines your best bet is to restore the table from backup.